# giving 2 diff users access to a folder

Tags: bash, sftp, chmod, umask

I need to give access to 2 users one with read access and other with write access to a particular folder(/folder). Both the users are supposed to be in the same group(sftp)

user with read access: readsftp
user with write access: writesftp

I have done

```
useradd -G sftp readsftp
useradd -G sftp writesftp
```

Now the user writesftp should be able to write files to /folder and user readsftp should be able to only read files in the folder /folder

The vipw files read

```
36 sftp:x:47173:47173::/data:/bin/sh
37 ft:x:1002:1002::/home/ft:/bin/bash
38 readsftp:x:47176:47173::/data:/bin/sh
39 writeuser:x:47177:47173::/data:/bin/sh
```

Have I changed it rightly?
(Please observe the ID's)

Could you please help me do this by using sticky bit, and umask and chmod? In the /folder folder
I have previously changed files and folder permissions using chmod and I am unable to get through the right understanding on how to do it wrt users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to accomplish this with standard Unix permissions would be to set the ownership to `writesftp:sftp` and permissions `g+r,u+rw`. Otherwise you need to use ACLs and, by extension, an FS that supports ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to transfer the ownership of the folder (recursively) to `writeftp` and the group ownership to `sftp`:

```
sudo chown -R writeftp:sftp /path/to/folder
```

Then you enable executable permissions for the group to all folders and full permissions to the owner:

```
find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```

and set read permissions for all files to the group and read/write permissions for the owner for all files:

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

---

Following the above steps you'll solve your problem, but however, there are better solutions for your problem. You could use `ACL`s (access control lists) on that file system or use `SELinux` while the latter is much more complicated to configure and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, 
I wanted to clarify on this. It would be of great help in me getting a clear understanding

so by executing these 3 commands, we get is the write user is now the owner of sftp and has rwx access where as the read user which is a part of the group sftp has only r-x access?

Then you enable executable permissions for the group to all folders and full permissions to the owner:

    find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;

Does this give access to all the folders inside /path/to/folder? or all the folders you mean on the system?

Comment: To all folders inside `/path/to/folder`